# start multiple processes parallelly

Tags: c, service, process, operating-system, system

I have an array of processes, and I have to implement all of them parallelly. As the number of processes depends on the size of the array, how do I carry out this question? I'm assuming I have to use fork() or threads but I am not sure how. And how do I return immediately after the process has been carried out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First let's get a few things straight:

- fork() is on POSIX systems the system call to split one process into two. The child process will be indicated by a return code of 0, and the parent by The Pid of the child (returning immediately while the child may be created/executing/dying). Aside from that, the two are essentially identical, which means the child needs to carry out the specific sub-processing (usually by means of execve()ing) another binary), while the parent wait4()s the child. Another option is to not wait4(), but instead listen for SIGCHLD, sent when the child terminates.
- Multiple threads all happen in the same process. Meaning that the sub processing is carried out by code blocks/functions in the same address space.

It's not clear from your question - so - If your array of processes is essentially an array of command lines, you use fork() and execve(), above. If it's an array of functions, use threads.